# Why can't I add a key and value when PHP array_key_exists is FALSE?

Tags: php, foreach, array-merge, array-push, array-combine

I am simply trying to add a set of keys and values to an array if and only if they are not already in the array. I need to add d1 thru d20 when they are not already in the array,

Here is my code.

print_r($demos_keys)

```
Array
(
    [0] => d01
    [1] => firstname
    [2] => lastname
    [3] => email
    [4] => d02
    [5] => d03
    [6] => partnerid
)
```

```
$counter=0;
foreach ($csvdata as $row) {
    if ($counter > 0) {
    $rowdata_tmp = explode(',', trim($row));
    $rowdata_tmp['partnerid'] = $partnerid;
    $rowdata[] = array_combine($demos_keys, $rowdata_tmp);


//Fails to add 'd04'
        // if(isset($rowdata['d04'])){
        // $x=1;
        // } else {
            // $rowdata['d04']='';
        // }

//Fails to add 'd04'
        // if(isset($rowdata['d04'])){
        // $x=1;
        // } else {
            // $row['d04']='';
        // }
        
//Fails 
    if (array_key_exists('d04',$rowdata)==FALSE) {$rowdata['d04'] = '';}
    }

//Fails 
    if (array_key_exists('d04',$rowdata)==FALSE) {$row['d04'] = '';}
    }


    $counter = $counter + 1;
    
}
```

print_r($rowdata);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [d01] => 1
            [firstname] => Fred
            [lastname] => Dryer
            [email] => FredDryer1@email.com
            [d02] => Backfield
            [d03] => North
            [partnerid] => 14
        )
```

I CAN add *d04* by inserting *$rowdata_tmp['d04'] = '';* before the *array_combine* statement, but the problem is that *d04* will sometimes already be present in demos_keys.

Can someone help? I'm dying here.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Also could you please add a [mre]!

Comment: Do you really want to create a 2-dimensional array? `$rowdata[] =` is creating a new row in the array, but then you're checking for the key in the top-level array, not the row.

Comment: I suspect that should just be `$rowdata =`

Comment: Can you clarify which array you want to modify when? Initially, you dump `$demos_keys`, afterwards you use `$rowdata` and `$rowdata_tmp`  and `$row`

Comment: Also, what does "fails to add" mean? Is there any error message given, or is anything just not working as expected?

Comment: What is `$x` for?

Comment: @ostone It must have been "minimally reproducible" since Barmar was able to solve it. Thank you Barmar. I think the downvote is a bit harsh.

Comment: @nicohaase  I was trying to update rowdata as indicate in the array_key_exists and final print_r statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for the key in the top-level `$rowdata` array, not the new row that you're adding to the array.

```
$rowdata_tmp = explode(',', trim($row));
$rowdata_tmp[] = $partnerid;
$new_row = array_combine($demos_keys, $rowdata_tmp);
if (isset($new_row['d04'])) {
    $x = 1;
} else {
    $new_row['d04'] = '';
}
$rowdata[] = $new_row;
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. Still learning here. Much appreciated.